Jest configuration for Angular 15 throwing : Missing semicolon error for test case
I'm trying to configure Jest in my Angular 15 application.
Jest config:
const jestPreset = require('jest-preset-angular/jest-preset');
const { globals } = jestPreset;
const tsjest = globals['ts-jest'];

const tsjestOverrides = {
  ...tsjest,
  tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.spec.json'
};
const globalOverrides = {
  ...globals,
  'ts-jest': { ...tsjestOverrides }
};

module.exports = {
  ...jestPreset,
  globals: { ...globalOverrides },
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
    reporters: [
    "default",
    ["./node_modules/jest-html-reporter", {
      pageTitle: "Test Report"
    }]
  ]
};

tsconfig.spec.json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
      "types": [
          "jest",
          "node",
          "googlemaps",
          "offscreencanvas"
      ],
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "module": "CommonJs",
  },
  // "files": ["./setup.jest.ts"],
  "include": [
      "projects/design/src/app/**/*.spec.ts",
      "projects/design/src/app/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}

tsconfig.json
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "api-management": [
        "dist/api-management/api-management",
        "dist/api-management"
      ],
      "lib-ui-component": [
        "dist/lib-ui-component/lib-ui-component",
        "dist/lib-ui-component"
      ],
      "@api/*": ["./projects/api-management/src/*"],
      "@design/*": ["./projects/design/src/app/design/*"],
      "@lib-ui/*": ["./projects/lib-ui-component/src/*"]
      
    },
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,

    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "es2019", "dom"],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "extendedDiagnostics": {
      "checks": {
        "optionalChainNotNullable": "suppress"
      }
    },
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
  }
}

setup-jest.ts
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';

Test file
describe('BatteryConfigurationComponent', () => {
  let storeMock: Store<DesignState>;
  let matDialogMock: MatDialog;
  let openNotificationServiceMock: openNotificationService;
  let SettingsServiceMock: SettingsService;
  let ViewContainerRefMock: ViewContainerRef;
  let ComponentFactoryResolverMock: ComponentFactoryResolver;
  let TranslateServiceMock: TranslateService;
  let component: BatteryConfigurationComponent;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [component],
      providers: [storeMock, matDialogMock, openNotificationServiceMock, SettingsServiceMock, ViewContainerRefMock, ComponentFactoryResolverMock, TranslateServiceMock],
    });
  })
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
});

Error I am facing is:

I think my config is not able to understand Typescript.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

It was an issue with my outdate node version I had to upgrade it till v18.10.0 at least and I was on v16

Look at the error message location carefully, and you will find that the issue is at the colon. The colon is used by TypeScript to define types, but this syntax is not recognized by JavaScript. So, the root cause is that Jest cannot parse TypeScript files. Jest requires specific presets to parse certain types of files. For Angular projects, you can use jest-preset-angular.
For how to integrate Jest into an Angular project, you can refer to the following steps:

Install jest
npm install jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest
In your project root, create file setup-jest.ts with the following content:
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
Create the jest.config.js file in your project root with the following content:
module.exports = {
  preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
  globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
};


Adjust your tsconfig.spec.json in your project root
{
   "extends": "./tsconfig.json",  
   "compilerOptions": {  
      "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",  
      "module": "CommonJs",  
      "types": ["jest"]  
   },  
   "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]  
 };


update package.json file in your project root as below.
 "test": "jest --verbose",
 "test:watch": "jest --watch"


Open your terminal and run command: npm run test, enjoy!

